# How create a flutter bottom Navigation bar like instagram?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hey there is a problem that I couldn't find a solution on Youtube...if you see instagram bottom navigationbar, when you are in explore tab and you want to back, the app wouldn't close and it will move to forExample home tab. There is a rule which app will not close after pressing back button. Thanks

Comment: You can use `WillPopScope` widget

Comment: could you share your code which you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme send you some code for this. It will add extra functionality to your exiting.

Wrap the dashboard in a WillPopScope. This listens for any attempts to go back and executes whatever function you gave it. In this case, when i try to exit, It'll ask me to confirm.

```
DateTime currentBackPressTime;

Future<bool> onWillPop() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      CommunicationServices().showSnackBar(
        "Press back once more to exit $capitalizedAppName",
        context,
      );
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }
```

Then wrap the main body of your app in Willpopscope. PS: Don't wrap MAterial App. Wrap whichever widget is shown after the splashscreen. For me, its usualy a widget i name dashboard.

```
return WillPopScope(
onWillPop: onWillPop,
child: YourStuff()
)
```

You can do whatever you want in onWillPop. You can use the page controller you're using on the dashboard to navigate to the central page before exiting.

Another good idea is to do what snaptube does. Show them a modal bottom sheet offering them some nice discounts to keep them in the app. Add a button at the bottom of the sheet labelled "No thanks. Exit" and on Tap, call

```
SystemNavigator.pop()
```

Like this

```
Future<bool> onWillPop() {
return showModalBottomSheet(
blah blah blah. I'm too lazy to type this code, but I'm sure you `get my point)`
}
```

EDIT: Communication services is just how i centralize my communication code. You can use

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar
```